# The Image file path is not storing exactly in to Mysql database, but showing correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm developing a student results portal, in the student details entry form I've inserted an photo upload button

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="stuImage" />
```

Selecting path for Image, shows below path which is correct and storing into PHP MySQL Database with "ImagePath TYPE:TEXT(500)" Column.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\office\school\img\pp_2.jpg
```

but, looking into database table the path is inserted as below

```
C:xampphtdocsofficeschoolimgpp_3.jpg
```

which is meaningless. Even after making some changes, like changed the ImagePath COLUMN TYPE to VARCHAR(250), and uploaded another image path but still the path is inserted as meaningless (with no slashes).

Can anyone tell me what mistake I am having and suggest some answer.

Thanks in advance.

Database Input Query:

```
INSERT INTO student (`StudentId`, `FatherName`, `StudentName`, `ImagePath`,  `DOB`, `Gender`, `Country`, `Barcode`, `GraduatedDate(9-10)`, `GraduatedDate(11-12)`) VALUES ($id, '$fname', '$name', '$imgPath', '$dob', '$gender', '$country', $barcode, '$grad910', '$grad1112')
```

Comment: include code of input of database

Answer (score 1):

Replace`\` with `\\`, because in sql query `\` are interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you may be stripping the backslashes on insert, any link to your sql query would be useful

Comment: `INSERT INTO student (\`StudentId\`, \`FatherName\`,\`StudentName\`, \`ImagePath\`, \`DOB\`, \`Gender\`, \`Country\`, \`Barcode\`, \`GraduatedDate(9-10)\`, \`GraduatedDate(11-12)\`) VALUES ($id, '$fname', '$name', '$imgPath', '$dob', '$gender', '$country',$barcode, '$grad910', '$grad1112')`, this is the query using to insert the details

Answer (score 0):

Replace "\" with "\\" will do it.

If this does not work try addslashes($str) in php before running insert query for inserting path in data base like

```
$imgPath = addslashes($imgPath)
```

or directly in the insert query

```
INSERT INTO student (`StudentId`, `FatherName`, `StudentName`, `ImagePath`,  `DOB`, `Gender`, `Country`, `Barcode`, `GraduatedDate(9-10)`, `GraduatedDate(11-12)`) VALUES ($id, '$fname', '$name', 'addslashes($imgPath)', '$dob', '$gender', '$country', $barcode, '$grad910', '$grad1112')
```

Comment: Replace "\" with "\\" in $imgPath variable before inserting into query

Comment: Actually I am inserting the ImagePath into database by getting the Path with JQuery `ImagePath = $("#image").val();`

Comment: try  ImagePath = escape($("#image").val());

Comment: ok, you can also try escaping in php by using mysqli_real_escape_string in insert query like

Answer (score 0):

```
$image_name = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);//file name
$image_type = pathinfo($file_name ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);// Extension

$server_path = 'school/img/';// server Path
$imgPath = $server_path.$image_name.$image_type;// Original image path
```

Now Insert work fine and **remove** ` from table field names

In view front of `src` attribute don't forget to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: I'm just inserting the image PATH ONLY. NOT the image and its content and thanks for your effort